# r shiny decision tree (tree with states and probabilities) functionality

Tags: r, tree, shiny

Does there exist a functionality to implement a decision-tree like interactive element in `R` `Shiny`? (By ' decision-tree' I mean something like [this](http://people.ischool.berkeley.edu/~hal/Papers/2004/DNC-HTML/graphics/DecisionTree.png) :) ).

I expect a tree to be quite 'branched' in my case and I wish I am able to present only a part of it (e.g. nodes, their parents [with siblings] and their children), allowing user to move it 'up/down' interactively.

Any ideas? Thank you a lot for any hint in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked around for something like this a while back and didn't find anything in R. However, D3.js offers very nice interactive visualizations that could be used. There seems to be some work on this that starts with python (see below). Creating bindings to js libraries is probably best done with https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets. It would be great to have a tool for decision-analysis in R. Keep me posted (https://github.com/mostly-harmless).

http://bl.ocks.org/pprett/raw/3813537/

https://gist.github.com/pprett/3813537

[how to explain the decision tree from scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557545/how-to-explain-the-decision-tree-from-scikit-learn)

http://www.garysieling.com/blog/rending-scikit-decision-trees-d3-js

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, Vincent! I believe the implementation from the http://bl.ocks.org/pprett/raw/3813537/ is sufficient enough. Greetings!

Comment: If you create something (in R) please let me know how it goes. This is something that would be of value to quite a few users I think