# is there any way to get samples under each leaf of a decision tree?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have trained a decision tree using a dataset. Now I want to see which samples fall under which leaf of the tree.

From here I want the red circled samples.

[image]

I am using Python's Sklearn's implementation of decision tree .

Comment: This: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32506951/how-to-explore-a-decision-tree-built-using-scikit-learn and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224526/how-to-extract-the-decision-rules-from-scikit-learn-decision-tree/42227468#42227468 may be relevant.

Comment: Is the left upper leaf left out on purpose?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want only the leaf for each sample you can just use

```
clf.apply(iris.data)
```

> array([ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
>   1,
>           1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
>           1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  5,
>           5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,
>           5,  5, 14,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5, 10,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5, 10,  5,
>           5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5, 16, 16,
>          16, 16, 16, 16,  6, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16,
>           8, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 15, 16, 16, 11, 16, 16, 16,  8,  8, 16,
>          16, 16, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16])

If you want to get all samples for each node you could calculate all the decision paths with

```
dec_paths = clf.decision_path(iris.data)
```

Then loop over the decision paths, convert them to arrays with `toarray()` and check whether they belong to a node or not. Everything is stored in a `defaultdict` where the key is the node number and the values are the sample number.

```
for d, dec in enumerate(dec_paths):
    for i in range(clf.tree_.node_count):
        if dec.toarray()[0][i] == 1:
            samples[i].append(d)
```

**Complete code**

```
import sklearn.datasets
import sklearn.tree
import collections

clf = sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)
iris = sklearn.datasets.load_iris()
clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

samples = collections.defaultdict(list)
dec_paths = clf.decision_path(iris.data)

for d, dec in enumerate(dec_paths):
    for i in range(clf.tree_.node_count):
        if dec.toarray()[0][i] == 1:
            samples[i].append(d)
```

**Output**

```
print(samples[13])
```

> [70, 126, 138]

Comment: print(samples[13]) here what does this 13 represent ? and does the output [70, 126, 138] means the indexes of the feature vectors ?

Comment: `13` is the node number

Comment: Can I get the decision path of a **test** sample, not **training samples**?

Comment: @AlaaM. you could run `clf.decision_path(my_test_samples)` and you should get the decision path for those samples.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters - That's good, thanks. Do you know a way to get a `dot` element though?

Comment: @AlaaM. have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43218264/2776376, if you pass in one sample you could color all nodes which have one sample and you can visualize the decision for this particular sample.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters - I'm not sure what you mean by "pass in one sample". `export_graphviz` gets a fitted classifier. So at that point the classifier is only aware of the training samples.

Comment: @AlaaM.Perhaps best to post it as a new question?

Comment: Hey! I am trying your code, but my plotted decision tree  (of a random forest) has 180 samples in node 0 and 29 nodes. While your code returns 23 sample[i] and 651 samples. Am I missing something?

Comment: @NoobProgrammer: Can you open a new question with your code? I have not tried the code on random forests.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69852142/extracting-samples-indices-of-decision-trees-in-random-forest